# How to display a physics simulation in the terminal?

Tags: python, graphics

I have created a minimal 2d physics simulation for a particular process. The main `api` for my "physics engine" looks like this:

```
add_object(center: list[float], particle_count: int):
    self.particles.append(...) 

advance(dt: float):
    ...some math stuff that updates the position of each particle...
```

A particle is just a simple class that has a position:

```
@dataclass
class Particle:
    x: float
    y: float
```

If I have a loop that provides a time (dt) value and calls `advance()` then the particle positions will update according to some underlying rules.

It now remains the issue by somehow displaying all these fancy computations, I was thinking that having simple shapes like rectangles made out of a number of particles each and displayed in a terminal window would be pretty unique.

Given a list of `Particles` how can I display them in the terminal using dots, or some other characters and update them as well?

Comment: Why do you want to use terminal? Why not use something that's been designed for 2d graphics like Pygame?

Comment: I will use Pygame, but only after I've tried and failed to do it in the terminal. For no other reason other than it would seem quite impressive having a physics simulation running on the terminal.

Comment: Just to clarify, something like Tkinter is not what you want, right?

Comment: I was hoping on a hacked "no external libraries" method, but any solution would be valid I guess. I do not know how to do this with Tkinter, but sounds interesting, I'll have a look at it.